# echo returns 'Invalid command line' when executed from execute_command_line

Tags: shell, cmd, fortran, cygwin

I'm on Windows with Cygwin with gcc 11.2.0, and my problem boils down to this Fortran code:

```
program test
implicit none
integer :: stat, ext
character(len=30) :: err = ' '
call execute_command_line("echo ab",cmdstat=stat,exitstat=ext,cmdmsg=err)
print*, 'cmdstat = ',stat
print*, 'exitstat = ',ext
print*, 'cmdmsg = ',err
end program test
```

I build it with simply `gfortran -o run file.f95`, then execute it from the command line.
When I run it from the Cygwin Terminal, it works as I'd expect:

```sh
$ ./run.exe
ab
 cmdstat =            0
 exitstat =            0
 cmdmsg =
```

(*i.e.:* `anb` is printed, the exit status is zero, and the return message is blank).

However, when I run the very same executable from CMD or PowerShell, it gives:

```
D:\test>run.exe
 cmdstat =            3
 exitstat =          127
 cmdmsg = Invalid command line
```

which seems to be an error from the shell(?) saying `Invalid command line`.

What puzzles me is not the fact that it doesn't work (it's Windows, after all :).  What really intrigues me is that if I run (what I believe to be) the exact same command manually:

```
D:\test>echo ab
ab
```

it works .-.

What I'm guessing is that the shell used by `execute_command_line` to run the command line is not the same I'm using by hand (even though [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gfortran/EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE.html) says it runs on `cmd.exe`, which then just adds to my confusion).  What's going on?

---

Boiling the issue down to:

```
program test
call execute_command_line('echo x')
end program test
```

building it with `gfortran -o run test.f95` then executing gives, on the Cygwin shell:

```sh
$ ./run.exe
x
```

and on CMD:

```
D:\test>run.exe
Fortran runtime error: EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE: Invalid command line

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x3ffa9569a in ???
#1  0x3ffa23cd4 in ???
#2  0x3ff9e40f3 in ???
#3  0x3ffaac704 in ???
#4  0x3ff9488ae in ???
#5  0x1004010c2 in ???
#6  0x100401105 in ???
#7  0x180049b8c in ???
#8  0x180047745 in ???
#9  0x1800477f3 in ???
#10  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
```

---

###### Updates and stuff:

For the younger generations, who don't use Fortran, this C program shows the same issue:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  int s = system("echo x");
  printf("%d\n",s);
  return 0;
}
```

Running it on the Cygwin shell prints `x 0`, and running on CMD prints just the exit status `127`, so it seems to be something with how the compiler is building the system-dependent bits of the code.

Just for the fun of it, I tried installing MinGW and compiling the program with that instead, and it works like a charm on both cases.  It ships with GCC 6.3.0, so I don't know if its an issue with the newer version of GCC, or if it's Cygwin's fault.

My problem is solved by using MinGW's GCC instead, but I'll leave this here in case someone in the future has an answer.  Thanks a lot to everyone who helped!

Comment: This is hard to answer for folks who don't know fortran literal string parsing/interpolation rules. How is `\n` interpreted inside double quotes? Is it two separate characters, or a single literal newline? The latter would make the problem far less mysterious.

Comment: ...one way you could check would be to ask Fortran how many characters long the string `"echo a\nb"` is. If it's 9 characters, you know `\n` is two characters (a backslash and an `n`); if it's 8, you know it's one (a newline).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oops, sorry.  Fortran does not (as far as I know) have C-like escape chars.  `print*, len_trim("echo a\nb")` prints `9` and `print*, "echo a\nb"` prints `echo a\nb` (`\n` are two characters).  I'm pretty sure the issue shows up without `\n` (shame on me: I didn't test), but I can confirm tomorrow morning.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've just tested, and `\n` is not a part of the problem.  Same thing happens with dead simple `echo ab`.  I edited my question to remove the unfortunate `\n` from the example

Comment: Thank you for the investigation -- I'm sorry to have pointed you in a direction that proved fruitless, but we did manage to rule some things out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Cygwin, I guess that the shell being invoked is *bash*.  Starting with *bash* :

`echo a\nb` on the command line gives me *anb*, and `echo "a\nb"` on the command line gives me *a\nb*.  What you get from Fortran, seems to be exactly what I expected.

If you want to see *a\nb*, I suggest that you do a

```
call execute_command_line("echo a\\nb",cmdstat=stat,exitstat=ext,cmdmsg=err)
```

You have also tagged your question as *cmd*. If you want to run this as a Windows Batch-CMD from your Cygwin executable, you would need to say this explicitly, i.e.

```
call execute_command_line("cmd.exe /c echo a\\nb",cmdstat=stat,exitstat=ext,cmdmsg=err)
```

Comment: The output from the Fortran program includes "Invalid command line". How do you see that matching?

Comment: Good point. This is an error coming from Windows itself. I could imagine that either no shell is involved (and since there is usually no executable file named `ECHO` in your PATH, this would not run). In this case, I would also try the variant using `cmd /c`, because ECHO is an internal command to cmd.exe. Invoking Powershell instead of `cmd` would also be an option.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't really answer my question.  I edited the OP to remove the unfortunate `\n` I had originally, because the issue shows regardless of that.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Did you try the suggestion at the very end of the answer?

Comment: @VladimirF Unless I made some stupid mistake, I did, and the issue remains.  I tested with `program test implicit none integer :: stat, ext character(len=30) :: err = ' ' call execute_command_line("cmd /c echo ab",cmdstat=stat,exitstat=ext,cmdmsg=err) print*, 'cmdstat = ',stat print*, 'exitstat = ',ext print*, 'cmdmsg = ',err end program test` and running the program from CMD gives the "Invalid command line" thing

Comment: Please put this code into the question, not a comment. BTW, if this really is the Cygwin compiler, than from [the docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/EXECUTE_005fCOMMAND_005fLINE.html) I would conclude that `sh` should be invoked. I just noted that in my suggestion, I did not provide the real file name for `cmd`, i.e. `cmd.exe`. I just updated my answer.

Comment: I just noticed that you wrote in your posting that the program works fine from a Cygwin shell, but not from Powershell. This may well be. I don't know whether there is some magic to do when running an arbitrary Cygwin binary from Powershell, but I would not be surprised if this does not work reliably. However, bash can be invoked from CMD, and you could try to execute your Fortran program by `bash -c run.exe`.

Comment: One more thing to try is to do just a `cmd.exe` without arguments, just to see that running external programs does work. If it does, you should get an interactive subshell from it.

Comment: @user1934428 Re `cmd.exe`:  I tried that, and nothing changes.  Re which shell is used:  Not sure this is a good test, but I used `whoami`, which is also a valid command on both cases.  I compiled with the Cygwin shell.  Running on the Cygwin shell prints my user name and exit status zero.  Running the exact same executable on CMD prints the same Invalid command line thingy.  Maybe this test was irrelevant, but anyway.  Re `bash -c run.exe`:  If I do that, then nothing (at all) is printed.  Furthermore, the idea is for the program to work on machines without Cygwin (thus the struggle :)

Comment: @user1934428 A simple `call execute_command_line('echo x')` which should work everywhere-ish fails (see the edit).  I am officially lost.

Comment: @user1934428 Doing the C equivalent `int s = system("echo x"); printf("%d\n",s);` prints `x 0` on Cygwin and `127` on CMD, so I am beginning to think this may be a Cygwin bug...

Comment: See the answer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/820168/run-cygwin-command-from-windows-command-line) question which perhaps applies to your situation. A program running on Windows needs a (possibly hidden) console window to ensure its happiness. Indeed, if you do a `man run`, you will find more information on this topic.